# How to fill the Pandas Dataframe based on values from another two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 4 pandas dataframe,
First two are Categorical and Numeric Values df,

```
Cat_data = [
        ['Color', 'red', 0.2543], 
        ['Color', 'orange',0.1894], 
        ['Color', 'yellow',-0.2836],
        ['Fruit', 'orange', -1.3647], 
        ['Fruit','banana',0.3648]
        ] 

Cat_df = pd.DataFrame(Cat_data, columns = ['Variable', 'Cats', 'Value']) 

Num_data = [
        ['Quantity', '-inf', '5', 0.2145], 
        ['Quantity', '5', '10', 0.0268], 
        ['Quantity', '10', 'inf', -0.5421], 
        ['Rating', '-inf', '0.5', 0.6521], 
        ['Rating','0.5', 'inf', -0.4378], 
        ] 

Num_df = pd.DataFrame(Num_data, columns = ['Variable', 'Inclusive', 'Exclusive', 'Value'])
```

In the Num_data 'Inclusive' and 'Exclusive' are checking values,

say on the first record >= -inf and < 5 ,

same for second record values >=5 and < 10, values come from Actual_df

Third Dataframe is the actual values

```
Actual_data = [
        ['yellow', 'banana', '4', '0.5'] 
        ] 

Actual_df = pd.DataFrame(Actual_data, columns = ['Color', 'Fruit', 'Quantity', 'Rating'])
```

Fourth is the Value DataFrame with column names same as Actual_df

```
Value_df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.zeros((1, 4)),
columns = ['Color', 'Fruit', 'Quantity', 'Rating'])
```

I need to fill the Value_df with the 'Value' from Cat_data and Num_data 'Value' columns corresponding to the data in Actual_data, I am not sure how to merge the four df's and take values to check the Inclusive and Exclusive columns along with that.

In Actual Data we have 'yellow', 'banana', '4', '0.5' the value corresponding to

yellow is in Cat_df as -0.2836

banana is in Cat_df as 0.3648

Quantity is in Num_df as 0.2145

Rating is in Num_df as -0.4378

My Result DataFrame of Value_df will be

```
Color    Fruit   Quantity   Rating
-0.2836  0.3648  0.2145     -0.4378
```

For the Cat_data, I did like

```
Value_df['Color'] = Actual_df['Color'].map(Cat_df.set_index('Cats')['Value'])
```

The issue for the color and fruit both orange, which value will be taken is the problem, so I have to match variable as well, I get error as

```
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can rely on the fact, that your ranges in `Num_df` don't overlap, you can do this as follows. Note I define some helper functions, you could also do without, but I think it makes it a bit easier to read.

```
# convert the datatypes (guess your real data does not store numeric values in strings)
Num_df[['Inclusive', 'Exclusive']]= Num_df[['Inclusive', 'Exclusive']].astype('float32')
Actual_df[['Quantity', 'Rating']]=Actual_df[['Quantity', 'Rating']].astype('float32')

# define two helper functions (or just store the categories / variables in different dataframes)
def get_variable_data(df, variable):
    df= df.loc[df['Variable'] == variable, ['Cats', 'Value']].copy()
    df.set_index(['Cats'], inplace=True)
    df.columns= [variable + '_value']
    return df

def get_num_data(df, variable):
    df= df.loc[df['Variable'] == variable, ['Inclusive', 'Value']].copy()
    df.sort_values(['Inclusive'], inplace=True)
    df.columns=[variable + '_inclusive', variable + '_value']

# join the first part by a regular join
Joined_df= Actual_df
for cat in ['Color', 'Fruit']:
    Joined_df= Joined_df.merge(get_variable_data(Cat_df, cat), left_on=[cat], right_index=True, how='left')

# now join according ranges using asof
for cat in ['Quantity', 'Rating']:
    print(cat)
    Joined_df= pd.merge_asof(Joined_df, get_num_data(Num_df, cat), left_on=[cat], right_on='Inclusive', direction='backward', suffixes=['', '_'+cat])

# drop the excess columns
Joined_df.drop([col for col in Joined_df if col.endswith('_inclusive')], axis='columns', inplace=True)

# the result of this is
    Color   Fruit  Quantity  Rating  Color_value  Fruit_value  Quantity_value  Rating_value
0  yellow  banana       4.0     0.5      -0.2836       0.3648          0.2145       -0.4378
```

As written above, the last step with the `merge_asof` asumes that your ranges contain no gaps, where you don't have a value and span the whole value range. Because of this, you wouldn't need to check the end of the range. However if that assumption is not correct, you just have to change the code a bit:

1. use `merge_asof` as it is, just alter `get_num_data`, so it also returns the `Exclusive` column.
2. use `Join_df.loc[Joined_df[cat]>=Joined_df[cat + '_exclusive'], cat]=defaultvalue` to delete the values that exceed the exclusive range.

Btw, it is really safe to do it this way, because if there is a row, in which the value of the `cat` column lies, then it will be selected by `merge_asof` because it searches for the biggest available `Inclusive` value, that is smaller or equal than the value in `col` (I mean, at least if you have no overlapping ranges, but it seems that is unlikely for a constellation as in your example).

Comment: Will converting the Dataframes to nested dictionary help?

Comment: Help for what? Pandas is pretty good for bigger datasets and the only point above, where it get's a bit tricky is the one with the ranges and you couldn't use dicitionaries for something like this effiently. you would start implementing loops.